# Explain the power rule for radical of x

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

I understand that $\sqrt{x}$ can be changed using the power rule, but I don't understand the mathematical reasoning behind it.

If $\sqrt{x}=x^{0.5}$, then how is this equal to $0.5 \cdot x^{0.5-1},$ and from there, how are you supposed to get to $\dfrac{1}{2 \sqrt{x}}$?

Comment: $x^{0.5}$ is not equal to $0.5x^{0.5-1}$, but the _derivative_ of $x^{0.5}$ (as a function of $x$) is equal to $0.5x^{0.5-1}$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Possibly you are unaware that $x^{-a} = \frac1{x^a}$ for any real $a$?

Comment: your question is not clear. Do you want to know why $\sqrt{x}=x^{1/2}$?

Answer (score 1):

Since $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\frac{\sqrt{x+h}-\sqrt{x}}{h}=\frac{(\sqrt{x+h}-\sqrt{x})(\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x})}{h(\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x})}=\frac{h}{h(\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x})}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$$
Also you have that
$$0.5\cdot x^{0.5-1}=0.5\cdot x^{-0.5}=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{x^{-1}}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$$